# How do I get my hp to work with my phone's micro sim

Tags: android, computer-science, cellular-network

I have a Verizon phone (Droid turbo) and an HP elitebook 8470p that has a Sim slot. I have already bought an adapter for micro SIM to regular sim. but i can't seem to find the correct drivers for it and for all I can tell, my laptop doesn't seem to detect it. how would i know if it detects it and what drivers would I need to use Verizon's network?
i have done a bit of research online, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt your Verizon sim will work with your laptop. The WWAN modules on your laptop don't support network of Verizon. They use 700 as primary band and 1900,1700 for support in densely populated areas but your laptop module supports just 1900, which I'm afraid might not be enough. Other possibility is that they might have simply not added your IMEI number to their whitelist.
I'd recommend you to test it out with a different sim (possibly a data only sim from a random MVNO).

Source: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03374369